# Multiple servlet mappings in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Is there any way to set via property 'context-path' many mappings for a same Spring Boot MVC application? My goal is to avoid creating many 'Dispatcherservlet' for the uri mapping.

For example:

```
servlet.context-path =/, /context1, context2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need a single Dispatcherservlet with a root context path set to what you want (could be `/` or `mySuperApp`).

By declaring multiple @RequestMaping, you will be able to serve different URI with the same DispatcherServlet.

Here is an example. Setting the DispatcherServlet to `/mySuperApp` with `@RequestMapping("/service1")` and `@RequestMapping("/service2")` would exposed the following endpoints :

`/mySuperApp/service1`

`/mySuperApp/service2`

Having multiple context for a single servlet is not part of the Servlet specification. A single servlet cannot serve from multiple context.

What you can do is map multiple values to your requesting mappings.

@RequestMapping({"/context1/service1}", {"/context2/service1}")

I don't see any other way around it.

Comment: Daniel I dont want to map uri controllers,  my goal here is to have many context mappings for tha same servlet.

Comment: That is not part of the Servlet specification. A single servlet cannot servers from multiple context. 

What you can do is map multiple values to your requesting mappings.

@RequestMapping({"/context1/service1}", {"/context2/service1}")

I don't see any other way around it.

Comment: If you look at  web.xml descriptor, we can add the tags<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/url</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

Comment: So, how to do it in Spring Boot?

Comment: Spring boot does not expose that configuration.

Answer (score 3):

You can create `@Bean` annotated method which returns `ServletRegistrationBean` , and add multiple mappings there. This is more preferable way, as Spring Boot encourage Java configuration rather than config files:

```
@Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean myServletRegistration()
    {
        String urlMapping1 = "/mySuperApp/service1/*";
        String urlMapping2 = "/mySuperApp/service2/*";
        ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(new MyBeautifulServlet(), urlMapping1, urlMapping2);

        //registration.set... other properties may be here
        return registration;
    }
```

On application startup you'll be able to see in logs:

```
INFO  | localhost | org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean | Mapping servlet: 'MyBeautifulServlet' to [/mySuperApp/service1/*, /mySuperApp/service2/*]
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found an alternative to using a filter described in https://www.broadleafcommerce.com/blog/configuring-a-dynamic-context-path-in-spring-boot that requires less code.

This uses RewriteValve (https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/rewrite.html) to rewrite urls outside of the context path e.g. if the real context path is "context1" then it will map /context2/* to /context1/*

```
@Component
public class LegacyUrlWebServerFactoryCustomizer implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> {

    private static final List<String> LEGACY_PATHS = List.of("context2", "context3");

    @Override
    public void customize(TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory) {
        RewriteValve rewrite = new RewriteValve() {
            @Override
            protected void initInternal() throws LifecycleException {
                super.initInternal();
                try {
                    String config = LEGACY_PATHS.stream() //
                            .map(p -> String.format("RewriteRule ^/%s(/.*)$ %s$1", p, factory.getContextPath())) //
                            .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
                    setConfiguration(config);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        };
        factory.addEngineValves(rewrite);
    }
}
```

If you need to use HTTP redirects instead then there is a little bit more required (to avoid a NullPointerException in sendRedirect):

```
@Component
public class LegacyUrlWebServerFactoryCustomizer implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> {

    private static final List<String> LEGACY_PATHS = List.of("context2", "context3");

    @Override
    public void customize(TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory) {
        RewriteValve rewrite = new RewriteValve() {
            @Override
            protected void initInternal() throws LifecycleException {
                super.initInternal();
                try {
                    String config = LEGACY_PATHS.stream() //
                            .map(p -> String.format("RewriteRule ^/%s(/.*)$ %s$1 R=permanent", p, factory.getContextPath())) //
                            .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
                    setConfiguration(config);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void invoke(Request request, Response response) throws IOException, ServletException {
                if (request.getContext() == null) {
                    String[] s = request.getRequestURI().split("/");
                    if (s.length > 1 && LEGACY_PATHS.contains(s[1])) {
                        request.getMappingData().context = new FailedContext();
                    }
                }
                super.invoke(request, response);
            }

        };
        factory.addEngineValves(rewrite);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, clean and working solution 

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'server.contextPath' property placeholder to set context path for the entire spring boot application. (e.g. `server.contextPath=/live/path1`)

Also, you can set class level context path that will be applied to all the methods e.g.:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/testResource", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class TestResource{

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value="/test", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<TestDto> save(@RequestBody TestDto testDto) {
...
```

With this structure, you can use `/live/path1/testResource/test` to execute `save` method.

Comment: But how I map many mappings for a same servlet? That's my question.

Comment: Darshan,  can we do it using spring boot properties without creating new classes?

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers to this sort of question seem to mention that you'd normally solve this problem by configuring a reverse proxy in front of the application (eg nginx/apache httpd) to rewrite the request.

However if you must do it in the application then this method works (with Spring Boot 2.6.2 at least) : https://www.broadleafcommerce.com/blog/configuring-a-dynamic-context-path-in-spring-boot.

It describes creating a filter, putting it early in the filter chain and basically re-writing the URL (like a reverse proxy might) so that requests all go to the same place (ie the actual servlet.context-path).

Answer (score -1):

I use this approach:

```
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

@Configuration
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
  @Override
  public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    rootContext.register(AppConfig.class);
    rootContext.setServletContext(servletContext);

    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(rootContext));
    dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcher.addMapping("/mapping1/*");
    dispatcher.addMapping("/mapping2/*");

    servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));
  }
}
```

Comment: Which doesn't work if you don't deploy as a WAR file, this doesn't work in a JAR file.

Comment: I looked at the source code of spring-boot and in class ServletContextInitializerBeans there is a line:
   if (name.equals(DISPATCHER_SERVLET_NAME)) {
    url = "/"; // always map the main dispatcherServlet to "/"
   }
so it seems, they don't want to allow anything but / for the dispatcher servlet.

Comment: No it doesn't that only applies if there is no prior `ServletRegistrationBean`.